# Cargar datos dependiendo del día del mes en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente sentencia de SQL que lo que hacer es cargar los datos del mes anterior a una BBDD.

Lo que quiero es lo siguiente:
1.- si el numero del día es menos al día 10 del mes actual que me cargue los datos del mes anterior
2.- Si el numero del día es mayor o igual al día 10 del mes actual que cargue los datos del mes en curso.

Esta es la sentencia que tengo ¿Alguien me podría indicar como hacerlo?

```
SELECT 26,ROUND(ISNULL(convert(float,SUM(A.num_ActosRealizados))/convert(float,min(a.num_dias)),0),0),' ',B.ID,'CNT','S' 
FROM TA_ActosIndicadoresAnnoMes a WITH(NOLOCK)
RIGHT JOIN TC_Centro b WITH(NOLOCK) ON a.cod_centro=b.cod_centro
AND cod_Indicador=12
AND FEC_ANNOMES=YEAR(DATEADD(MM,-1,DATEADD(DD,-1,GETDATE())))*100+MONTH(DATEADD(MM,-1,DATEADD(DD,-1,GETDATE())))
GROUP BY B.ID
```

Este es el UPDATE

UPDATE TC_Constante 
set des_constante=CONCAT(
  'Altas de hospitalización ',
  CASE
    WHEN DAY(GETDATE()) >= 10 THEN CONVERT(int, DATENAME(month, GETDATE()))
    ELSE MONTH(DATEADD(MM, - 1, MONTH(GETDATE())))
  END
)
WHERE COD_CONSTANTE=26

y este es el error
Mens. 245, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 1
Error de conversión al convertir el valor nvarchar 'Julio' al tipo de datos int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías probar con varias condiciones dependiendo del valor de DAY(FEC_ANNOMES)

```
SELECT 26
    ,ROUND(
       ISNULL(convert(FLOAT, SUM(A.num_ActosRealizados)) 
     / convert(FLOAT, min(a.num_dias)), 0), 0)
    ,' '
    ,B.ID
    ,'CNT'
    ,'S'
FROM TA_ActosIndicadoresAnnoMes a WITH (NOLOCK)
RIGHT JOIN TC_Centro b WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.cod_centro = b.cod_centro
    AND cod_Indicador = 12
    AND 
    ( (
          DAY(FEC_ANNOMES) < 10 AND
          FEC_ANNOMES = 
            YEAR(DATEADD(MM, - 1, DATEADD(DD, - 1, GETDATE()))) * 100 
          + MONTH(DATEADD(MM, - 1, DATEADD(DD, - 1, GETDATE())))
       )
       OR (
          DAY(FEC_ANNOMES) >= 10 AND
          FEC_ANNOMES = 
            YEAR(GETDATE()) * 100 
          + MONTH(GETDATE())
       )
     )
GROUP BY B.ID
```

**Extra:** Sentencia update:

```
UPDATE TC_Constante 
set des_constante=CONCAT(
  'Altas de hospitalización ',
  CASE
    WHEN DAY(GETDATE()) >= 10 THEN DATENAME(month, GETDATE())
    ELSE DATENAME(month, DATEADD(MM, - 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE())))
  END
)
WHERE COD_CONSTANTE=26
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, como haría ahora para que si el día del mes es mayor que el día 10 me actualice el titulo poniendo datos del mes de Julio o si es menor al día 10 del mes en curso que me ponga datos del mes de junio. un saludo y gracias de antemano

Comment: Cuando dices 'actualizar título', ¿te estás refiriendo a una sentencia sql UPDATE?

Comment: Si me refiero a una sentencia UPDATE so tengo esta sentencia pero no se donde ponerla para que me actualice el titulo en función de los criterios de antes.UPDATE  TC_Constante set des_constante='Altas de hospitalización '+DATENAME(month, GETDATE()) 
WHERE COD_CONSTANTE=26

Comment: A ver si lo he entendido. He actualizado la respuesta con la sentencia update

Comment: SI así es muchas Gracias lo único que me salta este error cuando pongo la funcion NOW() Mens. 195, Nivel 15, Estado 10, Línea 5
'NOW' no es un nombre de función integrada reconocido y conLASTY_DAY me salta el mismo error.

Comment: Utilizas mysql u otra bbdd? Cuál?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Actualizado de nuevo. Por la etiqueta pensaba que usabas mysql

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona perfectamente lo unico que ahora estoy modificando tu update ya que en vez de que me diga en numero del mes quiero que me pongo al nombre del mes, actualizo mi pregunta poniendo el update y el error que lanza.

Comment: He vuelto a actualizar. Prueba de nuevo -cambio MONTH por DATENAME(month-

Comment: Tengo otro problema hoy al ser día 1 cuando la ejecuto todos los valores me los muestra a cero he probado a poner la fechas a pelo(201807 y 201808) y me siguen saliendo a cero. sabe por que puede pasar esto. gracias

Comment: Dónde tienes el problema? en la select o en el update?

Comment: En la SELECT  pero ya lo he podido solucionar poniendo lo siguiente FEC_ANNOMES = CASE
    WHEN DAY(GETDATE())<10 THEN
        YEAR(DATEADD(mm, -1, getdate()))*100 + MONTH(DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE()))
    ELSE
        YEAR(GETDATE())*100 + MONTH(GETDATE())
    END                  muchas gracias de todas formas.

Answer (score 2):

Suponiendo que tienes un campo de fecha asociado a los registros, añades esta condición a tu select:

```
...
WHERE IF(DAY(CURDATE())>9, MONTH(fecha_registro)=MONTH(CURDATE()), MONTH(fecha_registro)=MONTH(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
```

Considera que si el día del mes actual es superior a 9 debe buscar en este mes y en caso contrario en el anterior.

Comment: Muchas gracias, este es el UPDATE que tengo pero no se donde ponerlo para que actualice según las condiciones de la select. UPDATE  TC_Constante set des_constante='Altas de hospitalización '+DATENAME(month, GETDATE()) 
WHERE COD_CONSTANTE=26